# MySQL Authentication Method Error

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication, plugins, connector

Using the official MySQL .NET Connector (6.6.4.0, the latest GA release), I am trying to connect to my website's database but having no luck.

This exception occurs when trying to open the connection.

> Authentication method 'mysql_old_password' not supported by any of the available plugins.

My connection string looks like this:

```
Connection = new MySqlConnection( "Server=" + sHost + ";User Id=" + sUser + ";Port=" + nPort + ";" +
                                                    "Password=" + sPassword + ";Database=" + sDatabase );
```

I have tried with two servers but I am only having the issue on the one hosted at HostGator, the other is on our own Windows server and it is working just fine.

The MySQL information for the HostGator server:

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server version: 5.5.23-55
- Protocol version: 10
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

The MySQL information for the Windows server:

- Server: localhost via TCP/IP
- Software version: 5.1.66-community - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Protocol version: 10
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

I am starting to wonder if this is something I cannot fix (without leaving HostGator). And if it is not, would a different .NET connector be the best option?

If you need more information about either servers, please let me know!

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Hopefully someone knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is shown when you are connecting to a MySQL database that has its passwords  stored in the old password format (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html). Newer MySQL clients do not allow a connection to be made to databases using the old password format as it is less secure. Probably the best way to go would be to upgrade the passwords to the new password format. Then the MySQL connection can be setup again and your database will be better protected.

You can read about how to upgrade your MySQL passwords from the old format to the new format here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/upgrading-passwords-from-old_passwords-to-new-passwords